# speedtest-cli: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: testing, bandwidth

On 3 machines I get:

```
$ speedtest-cli 
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/speedtest-cli", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('speedtest-cli==2.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'speedtest-cli')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1986, in main
    shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1872, in shell
    speedtest = Speedtest(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1091, in __init__
    self.get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1173, in get_config
    ignore_servers = list(
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I have tested one of these machines on two different internet connections with the same result.

Why is it not working?

Comment: How have you installed it?

Comment: Anyway, I can reproduce with `speedtest-cli 2.1.2` on Slackware.

Comment: That https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/pull/769/commits/6e9a667b677b9dbc91a989ed1cdb343afbaf5273 fixes the problem for me.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk points to https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/pull/769/commits/6e9a667b677b9dbc91a989ed1cdb343afbaf5273 which fixes it.

Comment: The final patch differs slightly from the one offered in the Pull Request: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/commit/cadc68b5aef20f28648072cf07a8f155639b81dd

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From this speedtest-cli [Pull Request](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/pull/769), I gather the speedtest site have changed something in the response their API gives out.  Looking at the first commit in the PR, you just need to modify a single line in speedtest.py.

If you're in Ubuntu or similar, and you have the file in the location shown in your output, you can fix it with:

```
## Backup original code
sudo gzip -k9 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py

## Make the line substitution
sed -i "s/^            map(int, server_config\['ignoreids'\].split(','))$/            map(int, (server_config['ignoreids'].split(',') if len(server_config['ignoreids']) else []) )/" /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py
```

EDIT: the final patch is at https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/commit/cadc68, and published in [v2.1.3](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/releases/tag/v2.1.3). It's too complex for a simple one-line sed command, but you could still apply it yourself manually.  Or you could try downloading that version of the speedtest.py file yourself:

```
sudo gzip -k9 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py

sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/v2.1.3/speedtest.py \
 -O /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py
```

(Again, you should double-check the location of the speedtest.py file.  The above location seems to be common for Ubuntu, but not across all versions of Unix/Linux.)

Comment: This patch was publish in v2.1.3, tagged "9 days ago"

Comment: @SteveAlmond Thanks, I've added a link in my answer.

Comment: thanks, your sed worked for me, fixed on ubuntu !

Comment: Applying the patch gives `ImportError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'main'`

Comment: The top solution with the one line sed command worked for me!

Comment: Good fix. My paths are different for FreeBSD, which isn't surprising. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I got mine working by using these 2 commands:

```
sudo apt install python-pip -y && sudo pip install speedtest-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by:

```
sudo gzip -k9 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/v2.1.3/speedtest.py -O /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py
```

Answer (score 0):

@mwfearnley your solution worked, thanks!
Sometimes `speedtest` might be installed under a different location so maybe run the following instead:

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/v2.1.3/speedtest.py -O $(which speedtest)
```

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!  Note that /usr/bin/speedtest may not typically be the speedtest.py file itself, but a sort of entry point into it.  (You can see similar scripts with `grep EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT /usr/bin/*`)

Answer (score 0):

I was using it on Raspbian (Raspberry Pi) and in my case I was confusing the site-packages of the python installation of the user *pi* and *root* (sudo).
This command was fine:

```
$ speedtest-cli --simple
```

But

```
$ sudo speedtest-cli --simple
```

always crashed. This was because there was version `speedtest-cli-2.1.3` for user *pi* and `speedtest-cli-2.1.2` for root.

Since I was using the commands in a cron job, the command was always run with root and crashed. To overcome this I had to upgrade the package explicitly:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade speedtest-cli
```

Maybe this also fits for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
sudo apt remove speedtest-cli
sudo pip install --upgrade speedtest-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Python speediest-cli just uninstall and reinstall it:

```
pip uninstall speedtest-cli
```

then

```
pip install speedtest-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

speedtest-cli can just be downloaded and run from any local folder. This is how to download the latest version from master and run it:

```
wget https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/raw/master/speedtest.py
python speedtest.py
```